# What is wrong in my leap year code in py3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, leap-year

**The question is this:**

We add a Leap Day on February 29, almost every four years. The leap day is an extra, or intercalary day and we add it to the shortest month of the year, February.
In the Gregorian calendar three criteria must be taken into account to identify leap years:

The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
This means that in the Gregorian calendar, the years 2000 and 2400 are leap years, while 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 and 2500 are NOT leap years.

**This is what I've coded in python 3**

```
def is_leap(year):
leap = False

# Write your logic here
if((year%4==0) |(year%100==0 & year%400==0)):
    leap= True
else:
    leap= False

return leap
```

`year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))`

This code fails for **input 2100**. I'm not able to point out the mistake. Help please.

Comment: Note that ``|`` and ``&`` are *bitwise* operators. You should use the logical ``or`` and ``and`` operators if you are interested in a boolean result.

Comment: Your formula does not implement what you have written in text. ``a or b`` (and ``a | b`` for appropriate ``a``/``b``) is always true if ``a`` is True. Also, ``year%100==0`` is True if ``year`` **is**  divisible by 100. "divisible by 4 unless (not divisible by 100 or divisible by 400)" is ``year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 and year % 400 == 0)``.

Comment: `import calendar`; `print(calendar.isleap(2100))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are using bitwise operators **|** and **&** (you can read about it here - https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-are-bitwise-operators-in-python), but you need to use logical operators, such as **or** and **and**.

Also, your code can be simplified:

```
def is_leap(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and ((year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def leap_year(n):
    if (n%100==0 and n%400==0):
        return True
    elif (n%4==0 and n%100!=0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I like this one - it's not as compact as Arthur Karpenko's and it duplicates some tests (so it'll be slower) but it is much clearer.

Comment: But I would make the first test just `n%400==0` (the `n%100` test is obviously redundant) and remove the brackets around the `if` conditions because they look really out of place in Python.